# How can I tell ConTeXt to automatically rotate images to fit their dimensions most accurately?

Tags: graphics, context, rotating, automation

I have high resolution images that would be much more effectively executed in landscape format. Is there a way to tell ConTeXt to automatically place images in landscape format to suit their dimensions when fitting them to a page?

Comment: Are you talking about inline figures or about floating figures?

Comment: Floating, I believe. I'm using the "externalfigure" command and they are large enough to not reflow. `\placefigure[]
[fig:i2]
{The SDFN Diagram for Interview 2}
{\externalfigure[Chapter4/graphs/i2_rot.png][factor=fit,frame=on]}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of any automatic method, but what you can do is to define a custom style for the images that have to be rotated and use it for big images. Example:

```
\defineexternalfigure [BigImage] [orientation=90]

\starttext

\externalfigure [cow]
\externalfigure [cow] [BigImage]

\stoptext
```

Whenever you want to include a big image that should be rotated, you add another pair of brackets with the identifier (here `[rot]` for *rotated*).

Comment: I would change the name of the identifier to `rotated` or `landscape`. Using abbreviated names like `rot` does not fit in with ConTeXt naming scheme.

Comment: @Aditya The idea was to emphasize that it's an arbitrary identifier and not a keyword. I changed it to `BigImage`; that's what describes the nature of the image, `rotated` would describe *how* it is displayed.